# Sorting a dictionary that contains a class holding 5 variable by one of the class variables

Tags: python-3.x, sorting

I have a dictionary that contains keys that are made from a class containing 5 variables. I want to sort this dictionary by one of the class vars.

here is what i currently have

```
class Player:
    def __init__(self,name,wins,losses,ties,winpercent):
        self.__name = name
        self.__wins = wins
        self.__losses = losses
        self.__ties = ties
        self.__winpercent = winpercent

   # mutators
    def setname(self,name):
        self.__name = name

    def setwins(self,wins):
        self.__wins = wins

    def setlosses(self,losses):
        self.__losses = losses

    def setties(self,ties):
        self.__ties = ties

    def setwinpercent(self,winpercent):
        self.__winpercent = winpercent
    # accessors


    def getname(self):
        return self.__name

    def getwins(self):
        return self.__wins

    def getlosses(self):
        return self.__losses

    def getties(self):
        return self.__ties

    def getwinpercent(self):
         return self.__winpercent

    def displayHighScores(self):
        print("\n"," "*2,self.__name," "*(24-len(self.__name)),self.__wins)

    def displayplayers(self):
        print(self.__name)
```

I store Players like this:

```
def addplayer(players):
    newName = input("\nEnter new Player name or 9 to quit: ")
    wins = "0"
    losses = "0"
    ties = "0"
    winpercent = "0"
    if not newName:
        print("\nNo name detected try again")
        addplayer(players)
    elif newName == '9':
        print("\nReturning to Options menu")
    else:
        players[newName] = Player(newName,wins,losses,ties,winpercent)
        saveData(players)
        return players
```

Finally i am working on a sorted hi scores list. right now i can print my dictionary unsorted like this:

```
def printhiscores(players):
    print("\n"," "*13,"HiScores")
    print(" "*3,"Name"," "*20,"Wins")
    if len(players) == 0:
        print("\nNo current Players in memory.")
    else:
        for x in players.keys():
            players[x].displayHighScores()
```

DisplayHighScores () being a part of the class object.

I have been reading on dictionary sorting using

```
OrderedDict(sorted(players.items(), key=itemgetter(1)))
```

but this returns     **edit:TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Player'** and 'Player'

Again I am looking to sort my dictionary of players by their win attribute and then print this new order to a high score screen. Any help would be greatly appreciated. I will post if i make any more progress on my own on this.

Comment: Ah, so you now found it. So now you come to the second half of my answer. In future, please don't just change the premise of the question by switching out the error.

Comment: it was more of an issue that i ran one of my attempts to fix this error and posted the complete wrong error code. The edit was the error code i was trying to fix. Thank you very much for your help

Comment: This is why we ask for a proper [MCVE] that you test for yourself. For future posts, it's appreciated if you included the full traceback of your exception too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `Player` instances are not orderable however, as they don't implement comparison methods:

```
TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'Player' and 'Player'
```

If you wanted to sort them by the value returned, say, *wins*, then just access that information instead of just returning the value:

```
OrderedDict(sorted(players.items(), key=lambda kv: kv[1].getwins()))
```

Otherwise, give your `Player` class [rich comparison methods](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__lt__); methods by which to determine when one instance should be sorted before or after another. You'll also need an [equality test](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__). It's easier to just implement support for `<` (lower then) and equality, then use the [`@functools.total_ordering` decorator](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.total_ordering) to provide the rest:

```
from functools import total_ordering

@total_ordering
class Player:
    def __lt__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Player):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__wins < other.__wins

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(other, Player):
            return NotImplemented
        return self.__wins == other.__wins
```

The above makes two `Player` instances equal when their wins are equal, and orders them by that attribute. You'll need to adjust this for your application as needed.